# Core dumped after using fseek in c

Tags: c, file, binary, fseek

I wrote a code and I'm having some trouble with a specific part of a function. I get "core dumped" if I add the `fseek` function, but if I remove it, everything works fine.

This is the part of my code with the problem:

```
    FILE* fe;

    fe=fopen("fete","rb");
    if (fe==NULL)
    {
        printf("eroare");
        exit(1);
    }

    STUDENT* x;
    int i;
    long int nrfete=0;
    **fseek(fe,0L,SEEK_END);**
    printf("%ld",ftell(fe));
    nrfete = ftell(fe)/sizeof(STUDENT);
    x=(STUDENT*)malloc(nrfete*sizeof(STUDENT));

    fread(&x,sizeof(STUDENT),nrfete,fe);
    printf("%s",x[0].prenume);//pt verificare
    fclose(fe);
```

---

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54336521/core-dumped-after-using-fseek-in-c#comment95490780_54336521)

```
typedef struct { 
  char prenume[20];
  char sex;
  float nota;
} STUDENT;
```

Comment: `fread(&x,sizeof(STUDENT),nrfete,fe);` should be `fread(x,sizeof(STUDENT),nrfete,fe);`

Comment: I modified but i get the same error

Comment: Please don't modify what you posted, unless it wasn't the actual code you are having problems with.

Comment: Oh, okay. I understand. However, that mistake was not the problem.

Comment: How can the code possibly work without the `fseek` when `ftell` returns `0`, `0` bytes memory are allocated, and `fread` reads `0` bytes from file? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: I explained myself wrong. By "working" i meant "not having an error". I do not get the "core dumped" error anymore if i remove the fseek. I am sorry.

Comment: It is unlucky that it "worked" because in that case you are accessing memory with `x[0].prenume` you don't own. It still needs the MCVE. That will show the `STUDENT` definition, and whether its `prenume` member is a pointer or an array. If it's a pointer, the code will fail.

Comment: how STUDENT::prenume is defined ? as I can see, you print it as string, are you sure that you don't need allocate memory for this variable?

Comment: @sandro this is how i defined my structure:   'typedef struct
{
    char prenume[20];
    char sex;
    float nota;
} STUDENT; '

Comment: do not place code in a comment.  Rather edit the question

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("eroare");`  Error messages are to be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error is from a  C library function,  should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stdout`.  The function: `perror()` performs all the above, correctly

Comment: OT: Regarding the definition of STUDENT, a struct definition should always include a 'tag' name because most debuggers use the tag name to reference the individual fields in the struct.

Comment: OT: regarding: `x=(STUDENT*)malloc(nrfete*sizeof(STUDENT));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT: regarding: `fread(&x,sizeof(STUDENT),nrfete,fe);`  This is trying to read the whole file in one gulp.  However, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  In this case, the returned value should equal `nrfete`  BTW: the variable: `nrfete` should have type `size_t` because that is what the function: `fread()` is expecting

Comment: the call to `fseek()` has not direct effect on why the program causes a core dump.  Rather the problem is calling `printf()` to print a field that does not contain a string.  BTW `fread()` will not append a NUL byte to each field (and your question does not claim that each field is already NUL terminated.)  Suggest your researching that detail to determine if the file contains NUL terminated strings

Comment: when calling `fread()`, always check the returned value.  That would have told you that the call to `fread()` failed because the 'file pointer' is already at the end of the file (it would have returned 0)

Comment: @MaryPoppins Re: "However, that mistake was not the problem.".  Code has many problems.  That mistake was one of the many errors.  They all need fixing.

Comment: What was the result of `printf("%ld",ftell(fe));`?  Tip: recode as `fprintf(stderr, "%ld\n",ftell(fe));`

Answer (score 2):

Two errors in particular:

You must `rewind` or `fseek` the file back to the beginning, before `fread` is done. As it stands, it won't read any data and so the memory allocated still contains garbage values.

And always check the return value of I/O functions like `fread`, which would have told you no data was read.

Another problem is the buffer passed to `fread` which should be the pointer obtained by `malloc`, not the address where the pointer is stored. So

```
fread(&x,sizeof(STUDENT),nrfete,fe);
```

should be

```
if(fread(x, sizeof(STUDENT), nrfete, fe) != nrfete) {
    // report error
}
```

Comment: I did all the modifications, but i get the  same error

Comment: And you *still* have not posted the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Have you read the link? The MCVE is a **complete program** that can be copy/pasted, compiled and run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Perhaps out-of-memory.

Answer (score 1):

as I can see, you seek to the end of file

```
fseek(fe,0L,SEEK_END);
```

then you allocate data for STUDENT struct

```
x=(STUDENT*)malloc(nrfete*sizeof(STUDENT));
```

then you try to read it:

```
fread(&x,sizeof(STUDENT),nrfete,fe);
```

but I think you get an error here. Because you are already at the end of file. So you don't fill data, and you have garbage in the x variable. In this case x[0].prenume is not a null terminated string. So you get an error when try to print it.

to check if I am correct or not you can fill allocated memory with zeros after allocation, in this case you will not get an error (but the struct still will be empty):

memset(x, '\0', nrfete*sizeof(STUDENT));

you can also print the result of fread()

Comment: Thank you, i modified the code, but the error is not gone

Comment: what modifications have you made?

Answer (score 0):

```
STUDENT* x;
...
x=(STUDENT*)malloc(nrfete*sizeof(STUDENT));
..
fread(&x,sizeof(STUDENT),nrfete,fe);
```

`x` points to a memory block,  &x is a pointer of x which is only 4 bytes.

Change `fread` to the following should fix the problem:

```
fread(x, sizeof(STUDENT),nrfete,fe);
```